# Amazon S3 Bucket Large File Upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upload a CSV file of approx 5 Mb size to Amazon S3 using the [low-level api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html) using java SDK.

I am getting below mentioned error:.

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified
>   upload does not exist.  The upload ID may be invalid, or the upload
>   may have been aborted or completed. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code:
>   404; Error Code: NoSuchUpload; Request ID:)

Could you please suggest what would have gone wrong. I am using `us-west-1` region.

```
    List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new 
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(tempVariableBucketName, tempVariableAccessKey);
    InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

    long contentLength = is.available();
    long partSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // Set part size to 1 MB.

    try {
        long filePosition = 0;
        for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++) {
            partSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));
            logger.info("Upload Id " + initResponse.getUploadId());
            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                .withBucketName(tempVariableBucketName).withKey(fileName)
                .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(i)
                .withFileOffset(filePosition)
                .withInputStream(is)
                .withPartSize(partSize);

            partETags.add(s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag());
            filePosition += partSize;
        }
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(tempVariableBucketName,tempVariableAccessKey,initResponse.getUploadId(),partETags);
        s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        s3Client.abortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest(tempVariableBucketName, tempVariableAccessKey, initResponse.getUploadId()));
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the code please?

Comment: I have posted the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Pleas make sure our AWS S3 configuration :
     <CORSConfiguration>
        <CORSRule>
            <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
            <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
            <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
            <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
        </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Thanks Aman but this configuration is already present inside the CORS Configuration under the Permissions tab. Still, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One of your uploads is failing. You will need to catch the error from s3Client.uploadPart() and retry.

I recommend the following improvements on the simple code below.

1) Add an increasing timeout for each retry.

2) Process the type of error to determine if a retry will make sense. For some errors you should just report the error and abort.

3) Limit the number of retries to something like 10 to prevent a forever while loop.

```
// repeat the upload until it succeeds.
boolean anotherPass;  
    do {
          anotherPass = false;  // assume everythings ok
          try {
              // Upload part and add response to our list.
              partETags.add(s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag());
          } catch (Exception e) {
                anotherPass = true; // repeat
          }
    } while (anotherPass);
```

This Stack Overflow question has code for improving the error handling for your example.

[Problems when uploading large files to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698869/problems-when-uploading-large-files-to-amazon-s3)

Comment: I had earlier gone through the link you have mentioned. But couldn't succeed. Everytime I am getting the same error  **The specified upload does not exist. The upload ID may be invalid, or the upload may have been aborted or completed.**
Do I need to make some changes related to upload id?

Comment: I have posted the code. Could you check it please. I have added the retry blocked and tried once but no luck.Everytime I retried, I received the same error message **Upload Id is invalid**

Comment: Please update your question with the retry code integrated. Also add a print statement on error so that we know what error you are getting for each upload part.

Answer (score 0):

try this recommendation from AWS Team
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/CopyingObjectsMPUapi.html

add dependecy in your pom.xml as well before using the sample code above :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
         <!-- please use the latest version available -->
        <version>1.12.470</version>
    </dependency>
```

it worked like a charm !...

Answer (score -2):

I was able to resolve this issue by using **GeneratePresignedUrlRequest** feature of AWS.
But now I am getting a new error.**413 request entity too large nginx**. I have googled for the solution where I found that  I need to make changes in nginx.conf file of server.
Now the question arises that since I am going to have multiple instances of server/load-balancers, so, would I have to manually set it for every instance?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you resolved this issue with the GeneratePresignedUrlRequest feature? I am having the same issue, and can't seem to figure out to use that feature.