# S3 large file upload using signed linked

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to upload a very large file(more than 10G) to S3 using a signed link. The link is fetched from a server so I have no AWS credentials or bucket etc. Since the file is larger than 5GB the only way I have is a multipart upload.

My code is something like:

```
RequestBuilder request = RequestBuilder.post(uri);
request.addHeader("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256");
request.addHeader("Content-Type", ct);
request.addHeader("Content-MD5", md5);

MultipartEntityBuilder entitybuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entitybuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entitybuilder.addBinaryBody("file", file);

HttpEntity mutiPartHttpEntity = entitybuilder.build();
request.setEntity(mutiPartHttpEntity);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request.build());
String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

This fails with:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
```

I guess the fail happens because AWS allows maximum 100 requests per a connection and this does a keep-alive and tries to upload all content on a single connection. Is there a way of setting the size of each part and/or make Apache HTTP client to not keep the connection open?

I don't have to use an Apache HTTP client. Any way of doing this upload is acceptable so I also look into AmazonS3 client but all the [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html) I could found have AWS credentials. Is there a way of doing an upload using AmazonS3 if I have a signed link?

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `PUT` request instead of a `POST`? Please refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html) example (which includes signed URL generation which is irrelevant)

Comment: Have you seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698869/problems-when-uploading-large-files-to-amazon-s3)

Comment: You can check this blog post https://www.jtouzi.net/uploading-a-large-file-to-amazon-web-services-s3/