# What is the best solution for the big file uploading in React Native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am developing one mobile app using react native. It should include one feature to upload the big file to the server. I know there are some sdks in native iOS and Android.
But what is the best solution for react native mobile project? 
I try to use AWS to upload the big file to a s3 bucket. I can use AWS cognito and file transfer native sdks.
But that is the stream uploading. Any solution for the chunked uploading?
This app should upload the big file in short time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems when uploading large files to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698869/problems-when-uploading-large-files-to-amazon-s3)

Comment: I think yes. Thank you.